# select the data which is in unspecified format in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have to select the data from SQL server table which is in following format.

Ex table Name : sample

The table sample has one column named as Text and the datatype of that column is nvarchar(20).

so in that column I have a data like:

```
Text
-------
'aaa'                                                                          
'bbbb'                                  
'c'                
 ddd'               
'ee
```

so by using the above the column data i want the output as below:

```
Text
--------
aaa                
bbbb                 
c                     
ddd                      
ee
```

so please provide me how I will get this through the SQL server query.

Comment: What would you like to happen with these strings? `ab'cd` `'ab'cd'` `'ab'cd` `ab'cd'`

Answer (score 0):

If `Single quotes(')` is the only thing you want to remove then use `Replace` function

```
Update tablename set Text = replace(Text,'''','')
```

or if you want just to select the result.

```
select replace(Text,'''','') 
from yourtable
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast suggestion.

Is there any other way to get my requirement without update query.
Means by using any sub-string function or another way.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL `REPLACE()`

Try like this:

```
Select REPLACE([text],'''','') from Table_Name
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
;with sample ([text]) as (
    select '''abc'''  union
    select '''abc'    union
    select 'abc'''    union
    select 'a''b''c'  union
    select '''a''b''c'''
)
select 
    text,
    substring(text, 
        patindex('''%', text) + 1, 
        len(text) - case when right(text, 1) = '''' then patindex('''%', text) + 1 else 0 end
    )
from sample
```

---

```
text       (No column name)
'a'b'c'    a'b'c
'abc       abc
'abc'      abc
a'b'c      a'b'c
abc'       abc
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion.